# Git approach Should individual decide on merge conflict?

Tags: git

In my current project the PM always telling everyone to "push to dev branch immediately" without thinking about merge conflict at all.

The problem is when conflicts occur , the individual programmers who  working on individual features , they have no idea WHICH CODES should be alive , and which CODES should be cut off :O

But the PM keep telling the team to "merge it to dev branch" 
I'm new to git flow and need clarify does this normal to allow individuals push directly to dev ? thanks

Comment: A conflict usually involves two contributors. One needs to know how to find out who the other one is. The two have a discussion on which code should be reserved and which should be abolished.

Comment: Should it be better to just  leave the remote branches (of features) there  and let someone "pull" them to develope branch  .. ?? Instead of 10 people pushing to only 1 Dev branch ?? thanks

Comment: Can you get away with using a feature branch? You can't push against dev if there's nothing to push on dev! Either way, if merge conflicts are coming up so constantly and taking away from actual development time, your PM's "push everything immediately" policy might be something that needs discussion with the whole team.

Comment: If you have feature branches, I think there should be a role, one person or a team, who is in charge of integrating the feature branches like reviewing and merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, a developer would first rebase his/her topic branch on top of origin/dev first.
That way, the merge would be trivial (fast-forward)

```
cd/path/to/local/repo

git checkout dev
git pull  # update local dev

git checkout my-feature-branch
git rebase dev # resolve conflict locally if any

git checkout dev
git merge my-feature-branch # fast-forward
git push
```

The idea is to replay local commits on top of an up-to-date dev branch, in order to resolve locally any conflict.
And to test locally if everything is still working.

Comment: Rebasing the topic branch with orgin/dev may not always be the ideal approach. This entirely depends upon the project maintainers, how do they want to keep the commit history

Comment: @Vinay Agreed. My emphasis was more about *local* merge conflict resolution.